# Git gc and git prune warnings when git fetch origin is run

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-gc

Working with remote repository at some moment I started recieving this when I run `git fetch origin`

> Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.

> See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.

> warning: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
> and remove .git/gc.log.

> Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

> warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.

This happens all the time. I found somewhere that `git gc` should help but it works only once (or seems to work) - after this and following `git fetch origin` I get

> Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
> See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.

Later the situation repeats. I also tried to remove .git/gc.log - it doesn't help.

My git skills are really limited. Why do I get this warnings and how to fix the issue for long?

Comment: Have you tried `git prune` or `git gc --aggressive`?

Comment: Try doing what it said to try doing.

Answer (score 27):

This article helped me -

```
git fsck
git gc --prune=now
git prune  
git gc
```

And error should vanish.

Reference - https://medium.com/lynns-dev-blog/git-there-are-too-many-unreachable-loose-objects-c2df601b8001

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reference. It does make a difference when you read the explanation of the comments. :)

Answer (score 5):

This particular issue was due to a bug in Git (for which a fix was first applied in 2.20.0: see [commit <sub><sup>`3029970275b473dbf62149887a19a6b4879528d7`</sup></sub>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3029970275b473dbf62149887a19a6b4879528d7), which has a good description of what's going on, but see also [commit <sub><sup>`095c741edd1d9604b6c285000a836721fd69f051`</sup></sub>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/095c741edd1d9604b6c285000a836721fd69f051), which has a contributory effect and was fixed in Git 2.17).  If you had the buggy version of Git, it let too many loose objects accumulate over time.<sup>1</sup>  You can and should upgrade your Git version to one that won't let these objects accumulate so badly, but for now, just go ahead and run `git prune` manually *when you're not doing anything else with the repository*.  Then run `git gc` manually when the prune finishes.  You may need to run `rm .git/gc.log` as well.

(The problem will come back now and then until Git is upgraded.)

---

"Loose" objects are normal.  Their opposites are "packed" objects, which are stored more efficiently.  Normally `git gc` runs automatically now and then and notices when it's a good time to pack loose objects.  Packing too often reduces efficiency; packing not-often-enough reduces efficiency; `git gc` is *supposed* to figure out the right time.  But some Git versions had this broken for a while, leading to the problem you've observed.

It's not a *big* problem: it just means Git is being less efficient (slower to run) than it would be, if this hadn't been broken.

Comment: This is not very helpful without any information about the affected versions of git, or at the very least a little more information about the bug in question, like a link to a bug report for example. As it is, there's no way for anyone to know if the bug you mention is the cause of their problem.

Comment: @DanielMcIntosh: The actual situation is quite complicated. The initial *fix* is in 2.20.0. In any case, as I said, it's not really a *big* problem. The way you know you have it is that you get exactly the sequence of complaints described in the question. If you get other complaints, you have a somewhat different bug. Still, I'll link to the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Git to the latest version, worked for me to get rid of this error