# Where to find gc.log file mentioned in the "too many unreachable loose objects" warning?

Tags: linux, git, git-dangling

I'm working in a fairly big git repository with around hundred active contributors - so lots of new branches and commits every day, and lots of deleted remotes after the developers merge their changes to trunk.
After pushing to remote I'm constantly receiving warning:

```
remote: warning: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
remote: and remove gc.log.
remote: Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.
remote: 
remote: warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
```

`git fsck` at this point lists dozens of dangling commits. To remove dangling/unreachable objects I have tried:

```
git gc --prune=now
git prune
git gc
```

The following `git fsck` only shows one dangling commit. Subsequent pushes display the same warning.
So I'm thinking I should also find and remove this `gc.log` file to get rid of the warning. But I can't locate in on my machine. Is there some default location for it? Should its location be configured somewhere? Is the warning message misleading and there is in fact no such file on my machine?

Comment: If it exists, the file will be at your repo's `.git/gc.log`

Comment: Looks like you found the [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630383/git-gc-and-git-prune-warnings-when-git-fetch-origin-is-run). Did you try torek's answer from there? I.e. pause all activity, run `git prune; git gc; rm .git/gc.log`?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander as mentioned in the question, I did run `git prune` and `git gc` while pausing all other activity in the repo. However I couldn't find `gc.log` file to delete it. I haven't tried updating git though. That could possibly fix the problem.

Comment: @RomainValeri, it's not in `.git` directory of the repo

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, my bad I hadn't mentioned, that I was not making any changes to the repo while running those commands